# How to disable buttons from Button Helper for single image, and enable all this buttons for the gallery? (Fancybox 2)

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Fancybox 2.

HTML:

```
<p><b><h3>Gallery</h3></b></p>   
<br />
<p><a class="Image" rel="group" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3787/9028269192_9b4ddf345d_b.jpg" title="Tolpis barbata (mariluzpicado)">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3787/9028269192_9b4ddf345d_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="Image" rel="group" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3745/8971419780_cb88b22947_b.jpg" title="(dSavin)">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3745/8971419780_cb88b22947_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="Image" rel="group" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8522/8478415115_152c6f5e55_b.jpg" title="a ride in blue? (cembayir_photography)">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8522/8478415115_152c6f5e55_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="Image" rel="group" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8366/8483546751_86494ae914_b.jpg" title="reedit... (h_di)">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8366/8483546751_86494ae914_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a></p>
<br /> 
<p><h3><b>Single Image</b></h3></p>
<br />
<p><a class="Image" rel="single" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_b.jpg" title="Singapore from the air (Andrew Tan 2011)">
<img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_m.jpg" alt="" />
 </a></p>
```

By default the cyclic navigation is enabled ("loop" option is set in value "true") as for gallery, as for single image, and all Button Helper buttons are visible.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jKsWu/)

CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".Image").fancybox({
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
    title   : { type : 'inside' },
    buttons : {}
    }
});
});
```

If the "loop" option is set in value "false", then cyclic navigation is disabled as for gallery, as for single image, and for single image Button Helper buttons are not visible.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xVNXU/)

CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".Image").fancybox({
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    loop : false,
    helpers: {
    title   : { type : 'inside' },
    buttons : {}
    }
});
});
```

**1) How to disable Next, Play/Pause, Previous buttons on Button Helper only for single image?

+

2) How to enable all this buttons for the gallery, include Next button for the last picture, and Previous, Play/Pause buttons for the last image?**

I am trying something like this, but nothing happens:

```
afterShow: function () {
    if (this.group.length < 2) {
    $("#fancybox-buttons").find('.btnPrev').addClass('btnDisabled');
    $("#fancybox-buttons").find('.btnNext').addClass('btnDisabled');
    $("#fancybox-buttons").find('.btnPlay').addClass('btnDisabled');}

else if (!this.group.length > 1){
    $("#fancybox-buttons").find('.btnPrev').removeClass('btnDisabled');
    $("#fancybox-buttons").find('.btnNext').removeClass('btnDisabled');
    $("#fancybox-buttons").find('.btnPlay').removeClass('btnDisabled');}
}
```

Comment: do you mean, exclude an image from gallery? ...or while navigating through the gallery and reaching a specific image, you shouldn't move neither next or previous?

Comment: If the gallery is only one image, then there isn't gallery ;) so don't worry about the loop http://jsfiddle.net/RTNYX/

Comment: @JFK None of that.
I rewrote the question and gave an code example specifying, that I wished to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about finding elements and/or adding *btnDisabled* classes, etc. Just add this conditional in your `afterShow` callback :

```
afterShow: function () {
    if(this.group.length < 2){
        // gallery has a single element so disable loop
        $.extend(this,{
            loop: false
        });
    }
    // more options, etc. 
} // END afterShow
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcHVb/)** .... or your updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jKsWu/2/)**

Comment: Yes, you are right about that my previous question about Button Helper buttons is related with this question.
I have my personal non commercial website, where I helping the people with the answers about Windows.
I decided to create the Fancybox window, that would look like the window from "Windows".
And I tried to create one class for all type of images (single or gallery).
This question was the last step.
Thank you so much.